# window.location.href not working in forEach second iteration

Tags: javascript, typescript, foreach

I'm trying to download the multiple files using window.location.href. I'm getting the file urls from s3 and pushed into array which have the links. It was working only first iteration. In second iteration the file not downloading but iteration happen. Thanks in advance.

```
var urls = [
    "https://www.s3.com/files1",
    "https://www.s3.com/files2",
    "https://www.s3.com/files3"
];
urls.forEach(url => {
    window.location.href = url;
})
```

Comment: It only works for the first iteration because you're redirecting the user to the first URL, and thus they are no longer on your page...

Comment: Assigning a new URL to location.href constitutes “navigation away from the page”, so the browser will stop script execution and further processing at this point. (You could not load “multiple pages” at one time by clicking a single, normal link either.) You could try and generate an iframe for each item, and assign the URL as source of that. (That will fail though, if any of those URLs forbid being displayed in frames.)

Answer (score 0):

Consider fetch or some other API to issue XHR request. Afterwards, specify what you want to return for each of your call (I put the blob type).

When all actions are completed (fetch promises) you should get the result (res). If anything goes wrong handle it inside your catch block.

```
let arr = [];
const urls = [
  "https://www.s3.com/files1",
  "https://www.s3.com/files2",
  "https://www.s3.com/files3"
];



Promise
  .all(urls.map(url => fetch(url).then(res => res.blob())))
  .then(res => {
    console.log('files here', res);
  }).catch(err => console.log('error occured while fetching', err))
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first iteration the url changes, then the browser no longer runs the script you wrote.

It runs script which is associated to the new url that is currently active.
i.e. "https://www.s3.com/files1" in your case.

The correct way would be to use fetch or axios to hit those urls.